# How to distinguish 2 button base on their parent/ancestor element in Selenium (PYTHON)?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, web-scraping, xpath

```
<a href="/google.com">
<div> ABC </div>
<span>
<button class="btn"> Show more </button>
<span/>
</a>

<div>
<div>ABC</div>
<span>
<button class="btn"> Show more </button>
<span/>
</div>
```

As you guys see here, we have 2 BUTTONS and I need to click to BUTTON whose ancestor is not `<a/>` tag, because if I click to button whose ancestor is  tag, it will redirect me to other pages. So I don't want this behaviour.

The obvious solution is I can use absolute Xpath for this, but it's not a good way because HTML DOM or css structure could be changed so it'
s not stable.

So how can I distinguish 2 button, using ancestor or something related? I mean other better ways.
Thank you guys for helping me so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select a `button` that has no `a` tag ancestor can be done with the following XPath:

```
//button[not(ancestor::a) and(contains(.,'Show more'))]
```

Comment: Those extra parenthesis between `and` and `contains` are unnecessary. This should serve the same purpose `//button[not(ancestor::a) and contains(.,'Show more')]`

Comment: You are right, thank you. However I don't think the answer without these parenthesis will be significantly better. Or is it really matter?